# Apache mod_rewrite working with http but not https

Tags: apache-http-server, https, mod-rewrite

I am configuring an apache server to change URLs from [http://(IP)/users/testuser/test.html] to [http:/(IP)/~testuser/test.html]

This works fine, as such

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ /~\$1 [R]
```

However when someone does [https://(IP)/users/testuser/test.html] it does not change it to [https:/(IP)/~testuser/test.html]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, figured it out - you have to add the rule to a virtual host directive in the ssl.conf file instead of where I was trying to put it.

Comment: Please add this as a proper answer, and then accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the rule to a virtual host directive in the `ssl.conf` file instead of where  you were trying to put it.